# Selecting a DOM element from a JQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the JQuery object myDiv

```
myDiv = $('<div class="question"><b><span>MyText</span></b></div>');
```

How do I select the text with within the span tags so that I can do something like:

```
myElement.text = 'New text';
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$('span', myDiv).text('New text');
```

That selects the span *from within* your `myDiv` object, and sets the text accordingly.

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsCmU/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('.question, span').text('new text');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know beforehand what the element will be, but it will always be the most deeply-nested:

```
var myDiv = $('<div class="question"><b><span>MyText</span></b></div>'),
    nested = myDiv.find(':last-child').last();
nested.text('my new text');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tGwaD/).